# Why does java script click() function for asp Button is not working in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using java script click event to call one server function to assign some session values. But this java script is only calling in the Onclick event of the Anchor tag. this redirecting to other pages.

```
<a  onclick="javascript:SetSession();" href="Some other page">

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonId" Style="display: none;" OnClick="SetSession" />
```

Then the Javascript function is

```
        function SetSession()
        {   
            var y = some values;    
            $("#hiddenfield").val(y);   

            document.getElementById("ButtonId").click();            
        }
```

Then the C# code is like

```
  protected void SetSession(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SessionName"] = this.HiddenField.Value;
    }
```

Its working fine in all browsers except Chrome. Even it is not calling the Button.Click() Server function In chrome ! I need the same functions. AnyOne Know the solution for chrome ?

Comment: This is not related to the real issue but you have misspelled `HiddenFeild` in your server-side code

Comment: its ok... thats not the problem, problem is, its not calling the c# function only in Chrome  @slvnperron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `return false;` in javascript-function.

Comment: Thanks for Answering.  Its working and calling c# function. But it making one other problem. That is, after returning the false, It is Not redirecting to the href = " otherPage.apx"

Comment: You can redirect request after call SetSession on server-side.

Comment: No, these href  is binding inside a repeater and have to pass number of query strings, so there are several number of href. so manually redirecting is not possible.